# JSON with function value with parameters

Tags: javascript, json, function

i have a very little problem but don't know how to solve it.
I need to send a JSON with a function, but with parameters and this is my problem.

Sending a function in JSON is simple:

```
var jsonVariable = { var1 : 'value1', var2 : 'value2', func: function(){ alert('something'); } };
```

I need something else, need to pass the func function as parameter with parameters.

Example:

```
var jsonVariable = { var1 : 'value1', var2 : 'value2', func: funcParam(param1,param2) };
function(parameter1, parameter2){
     alert(parameter1 + parameter2);
}
```

But this don't work :(

Any help with this will be really appreaciated

Comment: That is not JSON. JSON does not have the concept of functions. It is simply a JavaScript object. You have to be more clear about what you want to send, where and how.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you want, but if you want to define a function which accepts parameters, you'll want something like this;

```
var jsonVariable = { var1 : 'value1', var2 : 'value2', func: function(param1, param2){ alert(param1 + param2); } };
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to be able to pass any number of parameters to the function? If so, try passing an array to your function and iterate through, eg:

```
var jsonVariable = {
    var1 : 'value1',
    var2 : 'value2',
    func: function(params){
        var alertString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
            alertString+=params[i]+" ";
        alert(alertString);
    }
};
```

and call it using

```
jsonVariable.func(["param1", "param2"]);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3DpS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that has closed over those arguments:

```
var send_func = (function( param1, param2 ) {
    return function(){
        alert(param1 + param2);
    };
}( 3, 4 ));

var jsVariable = { var1 : 'value1', var2 : 'value2', func: send_func };
```

So the outer function above is invoked, receives the arguments, and returns a function that when invoked uses those original arguments.

```
another_func( jsVariable );

function another_func( obj ) {

    obj.func();  // 7

}
```

Of course this has nothing to do with JSON. You won't be able to serialize any part of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **JSONfn** plugin.

http://www.eslinstructor.net/jsonfn/

It does exactly what you need.

-Vadim